# Complete Upgrade Failure

Tags: 14.04, boot, upgrade

Yesterday I upgraded Ubuntu OS to 14.04 "Trusty Tahr" by following the recommendation while inside Ubuntu.  However, it failed miserably and the only thing I get now is a black screen with the following:

```
BusyBox v.1.21.1 (Ubuntu 1:1:21.0-1ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(Initramfs) _
```

In other words Ubuntu does not seem to load at all.

I run Ubuntu as an alternative OS in separate partition on a Sony Vaio that also runs Windows 7.  It has worked perfectly for several years until now.

Since this is a critical problem for me - please help!   What do I do???

Comment: You can try running boot repair, but, when upgrades fail it is usually faster to do a fresh install. Your data in /home will be preserved as long as you do not format the root or /home partition when you install.

Answer (score 0):

Create a fresh install my friend.
Its always recommended to instead of an major LTS upgrades as some files remain residuals.

Its great you have windows7 running alternatively hence to start your startup USB installation from there.

Most importantly backup your data, I'm pretty much synced with Dropbox 24/7.